# How to share stream position betwixt functions in Swift?

Tags: swift, stream, swift2

I was surprised by the following playground I created after seeing some unexpected behavior in my code:

```
import Foundation

let bytes:[UInt8] = [20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70]
var stream = bytes.generate()

func consumeTwo(var stream:IndexingGenerator<[UInt8]>) {
    print(stream.next())
    print(stream.next())
}

consumeTwo(stream) // This prints 20 and 30

print(stream.next()) // This prints 20!? I expected 40!
```

I had thought that marking the `stream` argument as `var` to the `consumeTwo()` function, the stream state/position would be shared/updated as it moved from function to function. But that appears to not be the case.

Does this mean I need to make that an `inout`? And pass with the ampersand? When does one use the `var` if that's the case?

More generally... what is the right/idiomatic way to create a stream over a byte array which can be passed from function to function (e.g. a decoder) and preserve the position of the stream as it is passed around?

Comment: the parameter of you function is passed by the value, so it is expected behavior.  if you call consumeTwo(stream) twice or ten times, the function will print the same. var as a parameter of your function is still just the copy of your global var stream. if you need to share the same stream, you have to pass it to the function by reference

Comment: OK, did some more reading, and finally got the difference between `var` and `inout`. They looked similar and both made the compiler happy when I was ad-hoc'ing in a workspace. It makes me wish that Generators were objects instead of structs. I can't help but think that this need to constantly juggle reference vs value, is going to be a sword Swift stumbles on (sadly so, because I really like Swift)

Comment: you can define generator as reference type as well. see my simple example (as answer, just because i don't know how to put the code here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+1 for archaic English in the question title. :)

When you use `var` in a function signature, you create a *local copy* of that value. It's the same as if you did this:

```
func consumeTwo(stream: IndexingGenerator<[UInt8]>) {
    var localStream = stream
    print(localStream.next())
    print(localStream.next())
}
```

When the parameter is a reference type (i.e. a class), the duplicate "value" is a duplicate reference to the same object. But the thing you get from `Array.generate()` is a value type, so your local copy is a separate iterator with separate state.

> Does this mean I need to make that an `inout`? And pass with the ampersand?

Yes — for your simple example, `inout` (and pass with `&`) is a simple and idiomatic way to do this:

```
func consumeTwo(inout stream:IndexingGenerator<[UInt8]>) {
    print(stream.next())
    print(stream.next())
}

consumeTwo(&stream) // This prints 20 and 30
print(stream.next()) // This prints 40
```

Remember: when you want to modify a value type `in`side a function and later see those modifications `out`side the function, use `inout`. And the `&` goes with it, so that it's clear both inside the function and at the call site that this behavior is happening.

> When does one use the `var` if that's the case?

Use `var` for parameters only when you want to make a copy that's local to the function invocation. Admittedly, the use cases for this are few. Here's a contrived (and completely unnecessary) one:

```
func bananify(var strings: [String]) {
    for i in 1.stride(to: strings.count, by: 2) {
        strings[i] = "banana"
    }
    print(strings.joinWithSeparator(" "))
}
let words = ["foo", "bar", "bas", "zap", "asdf"]
bananify(words) // "foo banana bas banana asdf\n"
```

If you find this confusing, you're not the only one. For this reason, removing the ability to use `var` for parameters is a [planned change for Swift 3](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0003-remove-var-parameters-patterns.md).

> More generally... what is the right/idiomatic way to create a stream over a byte array which can be passed from function to function (e.g. a decoder) and preserve the position of the stream as it is passed around?

[As user3441734 notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34141081/957768), you can indeed create and use a reference-type iterator instead. Or you can write a reference type that holds and manages an iterator. For your hypothetical case of sharing a stream among several subsystems of a program, this is probably a good approach — [representing a shared resource is one of the canonical cases for using reference types](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-408/?time=2530).

Answer (score 1):

you wrote "It makes me wish that Generators were objects instead of structs."

there is no trouble define some generator as reference type ...

```
class G: AnyGenerator<Int> {
    var i = 0
    override func next() -> Int? {
        return i++
    }
}

let g = G()

func foo(gen: G)->Void {
    print(gen.next())
    print(gen.next())
}

foo(g)
print(g.next())

/*
Optional(0)
Optional(1)
Optional(2)
*/
```